# How to manage Premiere Files to avoid versioning duplicates?

Tags: premiere

With Adobe Creative Cloud it seems like every few months Premiere updates and then wants to resave my project in the new version with added numbers after it. It has really cluttered and complicated things. I'm sure if I was more experienced when starting out I could've avoided this but video isn't really my specialty.

I'm working on an all new promo video though which makes for a good opportunity to clean this mess up and avoid it going forward. How can I do this?

Here's a screenshot to show the .prproj mess:

[image]

Comment: Use folders. Drag old versions into a folder, and keep only the current versions in the top level. Another organisational rule I have is to keep source material, renders, and project files in separate folders (if not separate drives).

Comment: @stib please leave that as an answer, comments aren't permanent.